# How to use relative paths in C

Tags: c

Hello i am making a project in C that has two separate programs (I use codeblocks) and I have a file in one program that needs to be opened by the second program, how do I do that.
The scheme looks like this:

```
MAIN_FOLDER:
-First Program Folder
      - The txt file I need to open
-Second Program Folder
      - Here I need to use the file
```

It was simple if I was using only my computer, but it has to work on all computers. 
I hope I explained myself well
EDIT: Thanks guys for all the help and the quick answers, I needed to put "../" to acces the parent folder thanks again!!

Comment: Will both programs always be installed in side-by-side directories under a common `MAIN_FOLDER`? How will the programs be started? Are you talking Windows, Un*x or some other system? If they _are_ in side-by-side directories, and the "current directory" when running the 2nd program is certain to be its own directory, then `../PROG1/SHARED.TXT` should work, but there are many things that can complicate this.

Comment: @ryyker Yes, `..` (in both Unix and Windows) means "the parent directory". So `../PROG1` (or `..\PROG1` in Windows) will refer to a directory "parallel" to the current one. However, depending on how `PROG2` is launched, there is no guarantee that the current directory will be its "home" directory. Depending on the OS, it may be possible for the program to discover where its binary is (and thus to "CD" into that directory, and/or use it as the base of a relative path), but we need more info from the OP to be certain.

Comment: Thanks for the trick with "../" that was what I needed

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, if the first program is running and looking for the second, the path would be `./../secondprogramfolder/file.txt` on Linux/MacOS and `.\\..\\secondprogramfolder\\file.txt` on Windows.

Using a single dot to say "in this folder," and two dots to say "in the folder above me."

EDIT: Use the `../` on Linux/macOS and `..\` on Windows if you already know the folder you are trying to back out of.

Comment: Asking questions to clarify a key point in the context of your answer, immediately suggests that the answer cannot possibly be complete.  :)  (maybe remove the third sentence, and add it as a comment under OP.)

Comment: I do not have enough rep to comment under OP. Sorry, I will remove the 3rd sentence all together.

Comment: The rep thing is a nuisance sometimes.  But you're almost there.

Comment: By the way, your statements are true only if both programs reside in the same directory, which is explicitly not the case by OP phrases `-First Program Folder` and `-Second Program Folder` .  For your current suggestion to work, those two folders would each have to be siblings of the same parent directory, and you would have to use `../` or `..\\` to traverse from one to the other.  (..., and now you can leave that comment!)

Comment: Thank you! It looks like that is the case though, as OP specifies a "Main Folder" and then the first and second folders being underneath it, each with their own contents. I am just assuming that's the reason he'd be asking for relative paths. There was not a whole lot of information to go off of, so I will go ask that now!